# I need help for my algorithm, my program use opencv and python as language. So i need help from stackoverflow

Tags: python, opencv, lbph-algorithm

currently, right now I'm doing the final project. But I'm at the dead-end because I don't know what to do anymore.

```py
def draw_boundary(img, classifier, ScaleFactor, minNeighbors, color, text, clf):
        gray_image = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        features = classifier.detectMultiScale(gray_image, ScaleFactor, minNeighbors)

        coords = []

        for(x,y,w,h) in features:
            cv.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color, 2)
            id, pred = clf.predict(gray_image[y:y+h, x:x+w])
            confidence = int(100*(1-pred/300))

            if confidence > 80:
                if id == 1:
                    cv.putText(img,c_name + ": Match",(x, y-5), 
                        cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 1, cv.LINE_AA)
            else:
                cv.putText(img,"UNKNOWNS",(x, y-5), 
                    cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 0, 255), 1, cv.LINE_AA)
            break

            coords = [x,y,w,h]
        return coords

    def recognize(img, clf, faceCascade):
        coords = draw_boundary(img, faceCascade, 1.1, 10, (255, 255, 255), "Face", clf)
        return img

    while True:
        ret, img = video_capture.read()
        img = recognize(img, clf, faceCascade)
        cv.imshow("face detection", img)

        wk = cv.waitKey(1)

        if wk == 13:
            break
```

I want my code to close that when the image or in this case face is matched, the widow closes automatically without using waitkey. and also this is my first time asking people on StackOverflow, so can I have some of your programmer's knowledge for my question?

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: the program works but when I try to put 'break' below 'id == 1', the window for cam still looping. what I want is when the face match, it immediately close

Comment: @THQ07 Tip: you will get better help if you describe the problem in the title of your post eg "OpenCV window closes too fast" and if you provide a minimal example of the problem - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  I think `while True:     cv.imshow("face detection", any_img)    wk = cv.waitKey(1)` would have the same unexpected behavior as the long program you posted.  Doing this work *first* is you helping other people help you better and faster

Answer (score 2):

You have set `waitKey(1)` which means the window will close after 1ms. If you want it to be displayed infinitely, use `waitKey(0)` which will display the window until a key is pressed. If you want your window to be displayed for *13 seconds*, use waitKey(13000).